# Rest API - HTTP Get - Need assistance with passing parameters

Tags: api, rest, http, get

Currently we have the following link:

https://module.test.net:9000/?Userlist&apikey=ourapikey&model=events

Now events has two parameters which are startdate and enddate.

I am unsure of how to add the date parameters to the link.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to the URL like this:

```
https://module.test.net:9000/?Userlist&apikey=ourapikey&model=events&startdate=2021-02-03&enddate=2021-02-05
```